# Rolle's Theorem related Question.

Tags: calculus

Given an interval $[a,b]$ that satisfies hypothesis of Rolle's theorem for function:

$h(t) = \sin^2(t)$;      $[0, π]$

Find all values of $c$ that satisfy the conclusion of the theorem.

So, according to Rolle's theorem,

$$ h'(t)= \sin (2t) = 0\\t = 0, \pi/2 $$.

but the answer appears to be, $t = \pi/2$. Why $t = 0$ is excluded in this case?

Comment: In Rolle's Theorem, $a<c<b$. Note also that here $t=\pi$ is also a solution to $h'(t)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the theorem states that there exists a point c in (a,b) not in [a, b] such that the derivative is zero.